# Is it illegal for a hospital to hide the doctor name from patient?

Tags: united-states, medical

I had an ultrasound at a hospital. The doctor over there gave me some recommendations. I wasn’t sure about these recommendations and wrote an email to the management asking other doctors to review those recommendations. They did review and provided an answer. I asked for those doctor’s names. Hospital refused to disclose. Is hospital violating any laws?

Comment: Most of the relevant rights arise under state law, although some federal laws apply. The answer to the question is not necessarily the same in every state.

Answer (score 3):

In this statement of ["Patient Rights & Responsibilities](https://www.nashunchealthcare.org/patients-visitors/patient-rights-and-responsibilities/) from Nash UNC it is said that:

> A patient has the right to know the names and the jobs of his or her caregivers.

But I do not find any actual law that establishes such a right. Hospitals usually have a policy that doctors and other caregivers must wear name-tags and identify themselves to patients, but that does not necessarily apply to questions after the fact, nor can I be sure that any law mandates such a policy.